# Generalization of Rouche’s Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

The statement which I want to prove is : Consider any compact set $K \subset \Omega$ of an open set
$\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$. If $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic functions on $\Omega$ such that
$|g| < |f | + |f + g|$
on the boundary of $∂K$. Then $f$ and $f + g$ has the same number of zeroes in $K$ counted with multiplicity.

My thoughts : If I can show that I can use triangle inequality then I can deduce from Rouche's Theorem. But I am not sure if this approach is correct. Also I need to make use of compactness. I am unable to find the way out there too.

Comment: I have seen http://mathoverflow.net/questions/75716/general-form-of-rouches-theorem but I cant see why two statements are same ( If they are )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give only a partial proof supposing that $C=\partial K $ is a simple closed curve.
We first note that $f(z)\ne 0$ on $C$. If $f(z_0)=0, z_0\in C$ we have $|g(z_0)|<|g(z_0)|$ by $|g(z)|<|f(z)|+|f(z)+g(z)|$, which is impossible.
Put $h=1+\frac{g}{f}$. Then$$
\int_C \frac{h^\prime}{h} dz=
\int_C \frac{f^\prime+g^\prime}{f+g} dz-\int_C\frac{f^\prime}{f}dz$$
since $\frac{h^\prime}{h}=\frac{f^\prime+g^\prime}{f+g}-\frac{f^\prime}{f}$ which is easily seen.
 We prove that $$\int_C \frac{h^\prime}{h}dz=0.$$
This  gives $$\int_C \frac{f^\prime+g^\prime}{f+g} dz=\int_C\frac{f^\prime}{f}dz,$$ 
which ensures that $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of zeroes inside $C$.
Suppose that $1+\frac{g(z_0)}{f(z_0)}=-r, r\ge 0$ at $z_0\in C$, then by $|g(z)|<|f(z)|+|f(z)+g(z)|$
 we have $$|-1-r|<1+|-r|.$$
But this is impossible.Therefore $1+\frac{g(z)}{f(z)}\ne -r, r\ge 0,$  for all $z\in C$, and hence the image curve $h(C)$ does not wind around the origin. Thus we have $$
\int_C \frac{h^\prime}{h}dz=0.$$